# It’s raining today vs. It would rain around this time

Tags: idioms-in-context, discourse-context

I’m a Japanese English teacher. I come across a strange sentence when I’m correcting a student’s composition. Although I feel it’s strange but I can’t explain why. I need your help.

In this situation, which expression is more appropriate? Or another better expression?

Situation:
Two people are standing in front of a bus stop, talking. Then it’s started raining.
A person goes:
“It’s started to rain. Do you have one more umbrellas with you?”
Another one says:
**The weather forecast says it’s raining today.**

I feel the sentence in bold should be replaced  by the expression like “The weather forecast said it would rain around this time today.”
What do you think? Am I wrong?
I tried to put this sentence in Google but there’s no result.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, in this context, the weather forecast said **it would rain today** or **might rain today** or **it was going to rain today**.

The expression **it's raining today** might be used by someone who peers through a window to see what the weather is like.

Or, someone might say: **My son, who's in Paris, says it's raining there today**.

Two minor points about your introduction.
You can use **although** or **but** but not both.
Either: **Although I feel it's strange, I can't explain why**
Or: **I feel it's strange but I can't explain why**.

And either:
**Do you have one more (another) umbrella?** (singular)
Or: **Do you have more umbrellas?** (Plural)